# What is the value of $\frac{a^3}{a^6+a^5+a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\frac{a}{a^{2}+1} = \frac{1}{3}$ Then find the value of $$\frac{a^3}{a^6+a^5+a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1}$$

Any hints to help me?

Comment: Your hypothesis means that $a^2=3a-1$, so you can get rid of higher powers. Doing that inductively leads you to the solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since $a+\frac 1a=3$, one has
$$a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}=\left(a+\frac 1a\right)^2-2=7$$
$$a^3+\frac{1}{a^3}=\left(a+\frac 1a\right)^3-3\left(a+\frac 1a\right)=18.$$
Now note that
$$\frac{a^3}{a^6+a^5+a^4+a^3+a^2+a+1}=\frac{1}{a^3+\frac{1}{a^3}+a^2+\frac{1}{a^2}+a+\frac 1a+1}=\frac{1}{18+7+3+1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using $a^2=3a-1$ we can compute $a^3=8a-3,\; a^4=21a-8, ... , a^6=144a-55$ by iteration. Then your term equals 
$$
\frac{8a-3}{29(8a-3)}=\frac{1}{29}.
$$

Comment: Isn't $a^{3} = 3a^{2}-a$??

Comment: @AspiringMathlete: $a^3=3a^2-a=3(3a-1)-a=8a-3$.