# Grade 8 simple algebra equation help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I find this question hard, please help.
It is given that $x+\frac{1}{x}=3$
and $x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}=7$.

Please find the value of $x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}$.
Please show the steps.

Comment: Hint: what happens when you multiply the first two equations?

Comment: The second equation $x^2+x^{-2}=7$ follows already form the first one: $9=(x+x^{-1})^2=x^2+x^{-2}+2$, hence $x^2+x^{-2}=7$, and $x^3+x^{-3}=3\cdot 7-3=18$.

Comment: These two equations are equivalent!!!

Comment: The question originally gave the first part and I solved the second part myself. I was trying to do the third part and was too focused on trying the method I used on the second part (multiplying the power of 2 on both sides). I got dumb and didn't think of multiplying two things together. I got dumb. Sorry

Comment: The question has been solved already, see the answer of @mathlove [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260592/what-is-the-value-of-fraca3a6a5a4a3a2a1/1260598#1260598).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $(x + (1/x))\times (x^2 + (1/x^2)) = (x^3) + x + 1/x + 1/x^3$

Answer (score -2):

We have : 
$(x + 1/x )^3$ 
= $x^3 + 3x^2(1 / x) + 3x(1 / x)^2 + (1/x)^3$
= $(x^3 + (1/x)^3 )  + 3x + 3/x$ 
= $(x^3 + (1/x)^3 ) + 3(x+1/x)$
=>
$(x^3 + (1/x)^3 ) = (x+1/x)^3 - 3(x+1/x) = 3^3 - 3.3 = 18.$